# Get parameters from lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I am not very familiar with lambda expressions. So I have the following expression:

```
EnabledPropertySelector = l => l.FranchiseInfo.ExternalSystemType ==  ExternalSystemTypes.Master
```

And two properties:

```
public string VisibilityPropertyName { get; set; }
public object VisibilityPropertyValue { get; set; }
```

I want to extract some data from the expression so in the end I can get the values of the two properties:

```
VisibilityPropertyName == 'FranchiseInfo.ExternalSystemType';
VisibilityPropertyValue == ExternalSystemTypes.Master;
```

`VisibilityPropertyName` is always a string. This is the name of the property.
`VisibilityPropertyValue` can be of any type.

EDIT:

I have a lot of properties. Some of them are dependent on other properties. For every single property I have to manually write the name and the value of the parent property:

```
{ VisibilityPropertyName = 'FranchiseInfo.ExternalSystemType', VisibilityPropertyValue = ExternalSystemTypes.Master, EnabledPropertySelector = l => l.FranchiseInfo.ExternalSystemType ==  ExternalSystemTypes.Master}
```

Instead of writing all this I want to write only the expression and populate the properties from it.

This is the declaration of the expresion:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool?>> EnabledPropertySelector
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the first statement? You shouldn't need a lambda expression to access the properties of FanchiseInfo.

Comment: You don't extract data from an expression, you evaluate the expression.  As Nick asked, tell us what you're trying to accomplish overall, not just with this specific expression.

Comment: At some point I will be in generic context and call EnabledPropertySelector.Compile()(e) to get the value from the func. I want to populate the two properties from the expression in some earlier moment, so I can save some additional typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all, you need an Expression. What's the type of EnabledPropertySelector? It'll need to be something like `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` where T is whatever the type of "l" in your example is.

If you already have an `Expression` then you can use the Expression API to extract whatever you need:-

```
var body = EnabledPropertySelector.Body as BinaryExpression;

var left = body.Left as PropertyExpression;
var outerMemberName = left.Member.Name;
var innerMemberName = (left.Expression as PropertyExpression).Member.Name

VisibilityPropertyName = innerMemberName + "." + outerMemberName;

var right = body.Right as PropertyExpression;
var rightValueDelegate = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(right).Compile();

VisibilityPropertyValue = rightValueDelegate();
```

etc.

I really recommend doing some reading to properly grok the expression API before diving in though; there are a lot of corner cases depending on how flexible you need to be. E.g. is the expression always of the form `parameter.Property.Property == constant`? It gets really complicated really quickly, so you'll want a solid understanding of the fundamentals before trying to handle any real-world cases.

There's a reasonable [introduction to expression trees on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397951.aspx), but some focused googling might get you a better understanding quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Funciton` and `Action` class, I'm not very sure of what you want be able to do, but I can give an tip.
Functions returns a value:

```
Function<InputType1,InputType2,ResultType> functionVariableName;
```

Usage:

```
functionVariableName = (param1, param2) => {
                                 //...process both params
                                 return result;
                          };
```

Actions, do not return values:

```
Action<InputType1,InputType2> actionVariableName;
```

Usage:

```
actionVariableName= (param1, param2) => {
                                 //...process both params                                     
                          };
```

If the lambda expression is simple (one line, with out if expression) you can make the lambda with out `{}`:

```
functionVariableName = (param1, param2) => //process values and result;
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

if you want to create an IEnumerable where the two properties are equal:

```
var results = EnabledPropertySelector.Where(l => l.FranchiseInfo.ExternalSystemType ==       
ExternalSystemTypes.Master.ToString());
```